# Function in_array() - Look for values in multidimensional object array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I'm facing a bit of a problem I can't fix myself.
What I'm trying to achieve is sort of a search filter. I have an array which can variate between 1 row to +100 rows. 
The array is built like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => PK customer
            [1] => Call number
            [2] => Subject of the call
            [3] => Date created
            [4] => Date changed
        )

      )
```

Here is a real version of one of my array's:

```
stdClass Object ( [ReadOpenCallsResult] => stdClass Object ( 
   [ArrayOfstring] => Array
   ( 
      [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [string] => Array 
        (
           [0] => 180355
           [1] => C0000448207
           [2] => TESTDOC 
           [3] => 3-7-2013 14:20:14 
           [4] => 3-7-2013 14:20:14 
             )
       [1] => stdClass Object ( 
         [string] => Array 
         (
            [0] => 180355
            [1] => C0000448209
            [2] => TESTDOC 
            [3] => 2-7-2013 14:20:14 
            [4] => 2-7-2013 14:20:14  
    ) 
 )
```

I have a WCF webservice which generates an array of the result of a function in C# and then sends it to my PHP page.
Now I was testing the in_array function, it works perfectly with an easy array but I can't seem to make it work with a multidimensional array.
I store my array into `$_SESSION['searchCalls']`

I tested with all kinds of array's but I can't get the 'real' array to work.
I tried it this way:

```
$key = array_search('180335',$_SESSION['searchCalls']);
```

And this way

```
if (in_array('180335',$_SESSION['searchCalls']))
```

EDIT: I saw some really good examples, but.. is it possible to get all the values in the sub array when someone looks for 'C0000448207' and then get the subject of the call and the datecreated with it?

This is the function which generates the object arrays.

```
 public List<List<string>> ReadOpenCalls(int relation)
        {

            RidderIQSDK IQSDK = new RidderIQSDK();

                SDKRecordset inboundSet = IQSDK.CreateRecordset("R_ACTIONSCOPE", "PK_R_ACTIONSCOPE, DESCRIPTION, DATECREATED, DATECHANGED, CODE", "FK_RELATION = " + relation, "DATECREATED DESC ");
                var messages = new List<List<string>>();
                List<string> mess = new List<string>();

                if (inboundSet != null && inboundSet.RecordCount > 0)
                {
                    inboundSet.MoveFirst();

                    do
                    {
                        List<string> list = new List<string>();
                        string pkas = inboundSet.Fields["PK_R_ACTIONSCOPE"].Value.ToString();
                        string code = inboundSet.Fields["CODE"].Value.ToString();
                        string descr = inboundSet.Fields["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString();
                        string datecreated = inboundSet.Fields["DATECREATED"].Value.ToString();
                        string datechanged = inboundSet.Fields["DATECREATED"].Value.ToString();

                        list.Add(pkas);
                        list.Add(code);
                        list.Add(descr);
                        list.Add(datecreated);
                        list.Add(datechanged);

                        messages.Add(list);

                        inboundSet.MoveNext();

                    }
                    while (!inboundSet.EOF);
                    return messages;
                }
                    mess.Add(null);
                    messages.Add(mess);

                    IQSDK.Logout();
                    return messages;


                }
```

I solved it myself already, this is my solution which is kinda nasty but it works.

```
$roc = array('relation' => $_SESSION['username']);
$rocresponse = $wcfclient->ReadOpenCalls($roc);
$_SESSION['searchCalls'] = $rocresponse;

    foreach ($rocresponse->ReadOpenCallsResult as $key => $value){
    if (count($value) === 0) {
    }
    if (count($value) === 1) { 
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1){
            if (in_array($searchWord,$value1)){
                    echo "Value is in it";
                }
        }
    }
    else{
        foreach($value as $key1 => $value1){
            foreach($value1 as $key2 => $value2){
                if (array_search($searchWord,$value2)){
                    print_r($value2);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm always interested in better solutions, and maybe this solution can help someone else out too.

Comment: Is using arrays as object properties somewhat reasoned? Because you don't have array of arrays but array of objects that have arrays.

Comment: You'll need recursive function or iterator. I am pretty sure this is already asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: it's not array, it's object array.

Comment: This is just an example, it could go up to index +100, but I will always search on either Callnumber or Subject of Call.

Comment: array_filter is your friend

Comment: I tried all that kind of functions already, like in_array, array_key, array_filter, array_search etc

Comment: I found the solution and posted it.

Comment: @Marijke You should post your solution as an answer to this question and remove it from the question text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Nisarg this isn't an Array its an Object.  Or you need to update your question to show you are accessinng the object.

What if you try something like this

```
$SearchCalls =  $_SESSION['searchCalls'];
if (in_array('180335',$SearchCalls->ReadOpenCallsResult)){

 //do some work.
}
```

Comment: @Marijke Ohhh - I just noticed both your sub arrays are actually objects also.  YOu will need to search each individually, or move them to arrays.  Why are they objects in the first place?

Comment: My C# function makes them objects. Do you think it'll be usefull to post my function from the app too?

Comment: I posted my function too now.